# Drupal: HTML Button on page to match theme

Tags: html, css, drupal, button

I've got a simple question to ask this time that I'm hoping has a simple solution;

I made  a theme for my drupal website (using Artisteer) and now I want to create a page with a button on it that looks the same as my others, i.e: using the same css, and I just wondered how I could do that?

I've tried `<html><input type="button" value="More Info..." class="art-button" /></html>`
And I've also tried:

```
<html>  <div id="art-button"><input type="button" value="More Info" /> </div>
```

But all they do is display a standard HTML button and not the one I styled in Artisteer. I'm fairly certain 'art-button' is the right thing to use but if anyone knows for certain what the style is I need to use please inform me.

So, if you could  answer my question please I would appricate it!

Thanks In Advance,

Andy

PS I use openWYSIWYG to create my drupal pages if that makes any difference?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a button on your page and view its source code. Telepathically attaching stylesheets doesn't work on SO, you'll need to quote the code next time for a more exact answer.

WYSIWYG editors don't make much difference, but make sure your input filters allow for the HTML you're trying to use.

BTW, don't use Artisteer. It occasionally likes to generate buggy code for buttons and you don't want surprises like that :).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I figured out what to do thanks to the 'View Source' feature in browsers that I totally forgo about! I figured the input filter thing out with openWYSIWYG a few days ago, after I had lots of trtoubles with images! And as for the Artisteer things, it's a bit tough for me, as I've just spend £80 on a licence - anyway, I haven't had any troubles with it before and it's not like I'm going to be using it enough for it to really matter! BTW, I keep editing my comment because I keep forgeting you can't press Enter :P

Comment: hi, it's me again. Just thought i'd let you know how I did it before I went any further, So, after a added the code to import the css I use this code: `<ul class="arttabs_primary"><li><span class="art-button-wrapper"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><a href="/lffd" class="art-button">More Info...</a></span></li></ul>`! Basically, now I need to know how to centerize the buttons!? I've tried the <center> and <div> tags but they don't seem to work so can someone suggest how I can do this please?

Comment: With Javascript. You won't manage to do it with pure HTML and/or CSS, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When using buttons in Drupal you should set default CSS classes to them. If it is a submit button add

```
class="form-submit"
```

and if it is a normal button add:

```
class="form-button"
```

This default style in your current theme will be applied to your button.